# AVFrame buf size calculation

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

I am having trouble encoding a video with the ffmpeg libraries as i am getting segfaults and/or out of bound memory writing when i am writing raw video data to an AVFrame. I therefore just wanted to ask if one of my assumptions was right.

Am i right to assume that the size of `AVFrame.data[i]` is always equal to `AVFrame.linesize[i]*AVFrame.Height`? Or could there be scenarios where that is not the case, and if so how can i then reliably calculate the size of `AVFrame.data[i]`?

Answer (score 2):

It work in most of the cases, but I wouldn't relay on that for all different formats:-

AVFrame.linesize[i] = AVFrame.Width * PixelSize (where PixelSize eg. RGBA = 4bytes)

BufferSize = AVFrame.linesize[i] * AVFrame.Height

The best way, it should be by using FFmpeg's official [av_image_get_buffer_size](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/group__lavu__picture.html#ga24a67963c3ae0054a2a4bab35930e694)

```
int buffer_size = av_image_get_buffer_size(AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the pixel format. For example YUV 4:4:4, yes every plane is linesize*height. But for 4:2:2 it is linesize*height for the Y plane, but linesize*height/2 for the U and V planes.